# ElasticSearch vs MongoDB vs Cassandra for mailer logs

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, cassandra, system-design

I have a mailer system where in we send 1-2 lakhs mail everyday and then we store all the clicks / opens actions of those mail.

This is currently working fine in MySQL.

But now with increasing traffic, we are facing some performance issue with Mysql.

So we are thinking of shifting to Elastic / Cassandra / Mongo.

My possible queries include
a) Getting user which have opened / clicked a specific mail or not.
b) Calculating open rate / click rate for mail

I think cassandra might not fit here perfectly as it is well suited for applications with high concurrent writes but with less read queries.

Here there can be many types of read queries so it will be difficult to decide on partitioning key / clustering, so too mzny aggregations will be running on cassandra.

What should we use in this case and why?

We are anyhow working on both elastic / mongo to design the data model for both and then run some benchmarks around it.

Comment: If the data is going to grow huge and you are planning to get complex analytics out of it then probably you are going to use too many complex aggregations. In such a case elastic would be better choice.

Answer (score 0):

ELK stack (Elastic Search, LogStash, Kibana) is the best solution for this. As far as I have used ELK stack, it is fast for log processing.

Cassandra is definitely not the right option.

You can use MongoDB since most of the queries are GET queries.

But I have a few points why Elastic search gains power over Mongo for Log Processing.

1. **Full-text search** : Elastic Search implements a lot of features, such as customized splitting text into words, customized stemming, facetted search, etc.
2. **Fuzzy Searching** : A fuzzy search is good for spelling errors. You can find what you are searching for even though you have a spelling mistake.
3. **Speed** : Elastic search is able to execute complex queries extremely fast.

As the name itself suggests Elastic search is made for searching purpose. And Searching in mongo is not as fast as Elastic Search.

But Maintaining Elastic Search also has its own problems.

refer: 
https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/elastic-search-advantages-books/ 
https://interviewbubble.com/elasticsearch-pros-and-cons-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-elasticsearch/

Thanks, I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If I try to look at your Data Structure and Data Access pattern, it looks like you'll have a message Id for each message, it's contents, and then along with it, a lot of counters which get updated each time a person opens it, maybe some information like user id/email of people who have opened it.

Since these records are updated on each open of an email, I believe the number of writes are reasonably high. Assuming each mail gets opened on an Average of 10 times/day, it'll have 10-20 Lakh writes per day with 1-2 Lakh emails.

Comparing this with reads, I am not sure of your read pattern, but if it's being used for analytics purpose, or to show in some dashboard it'll be read a few times a day maybe. Basically Reads are significantly low compared to writes.

That being said, if your read query pattern is of the form where you query always with a message id, then Cassandra/Hbase are the best choices that you have.
If that's not the case and you have different kinds of queries, or you want to do a lot of analytics, then I would prefer Mongo DB.

Elastic search is not really a Database, it's more of a query engine. And there are a lot of instances where the data loss happens in ES. If you are planning to keep this as your primary data store then Elastic Search/ELK is not a good choice.

You could look at [this video to help come to a conclusion on which DB is best given what scenarios.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cODCpXtPHbQ)
Alternatively, a summary is @ [CodeKarle's website](https://www.codekarle.com/system-design/Database-system-design.html)